# Deseriliaze JSON object

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0

I am trying to deserialize JSON file but I am getting null values after deserialization. I am using Newtonsoft.Json. Could you please let me know if I am doing right? appreciate any help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("json4.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
}
```

### JSON file

```
{"$pArray": {
  "Items":[{
     "c_date": "13-JAN-2016",
     "c_summary": "test",
     "ItemDetails":[        {
       "name1": "TESTFN",
       "name2": "TESTLASTNAME"
      },
     ]}
]}}
```

My `RootObject` class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Items items { get; set; }
}
```

### Items class:

```
public class Items
{     
    public string c_date { get; set; }
    public string c_summary { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDetails> itemDetails{ get; set; }
}
public class ItemDetails
{
    public string name1 { get; set; }
    public string name2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of mistakes:

1. Your property name under `RootObject` should be `Items` instead of `items`
2. Its type should be a collection
3. In your JSON you have an extra level of the `$pArray` and only then the `RootObject`

All together:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public IEnumerable<Items> Items { get; set; }
}
```

See that JSON format is:

```
{"Items":[{
     "c_date": "13-JAN-2016",
     "c_summary": "test",
     "ItemDetails":[        {
       "name1": "TESTFN",
       "name2": "TESTLASTNAME"
      },
     ]}
]}
```

**If you do not have access to change the JSON** format or need that extra depth then add another object and nest the `RootObject` in it. Then if for the `pArray` look at the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm):

```
public class PArray
{
    public IEnumerable<Items> Items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$pArray")]
    public PArray Root { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This assumes he has access to change the json that is being serialized, if he's calling it RootObject, and he's serializing with something called `$pArray`, I would assume he doesn't control it.

Answer (score 0):

Your root object contains a `$pArray`, it doesn't contain a list of items. However, `$pArray` is not a valid name.

```
void Main()
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\t.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            string line = reader.ReadToEnd();

            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(line).Dump();
        }
    }
}

public class ItemDetail
{
    public string name1 { get; set; }
    public string name2 { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string c_date { get; set; }
    public string c_summary { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDetail> ItemDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PArray
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$pArray")]
    public PArray RootNode { get; set; }
}
```

is a more correct example, assuming you can't change the `$pArray`

Comment: I couldn't get this working. I am getting error message here: public PArray PArray { get; set; }